# How to search for multiple strings in logs using aws cloudwatch log insights query?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

For my aws loggroups, I want to write a cloudwatch log insgights query to search for multiple strings in the logs. I tried something like this :

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like /(?i)\$\{jndi/
| filter @message like /(?i)\$\{\$\{lower\:j/
| sort @timestamp desc
```

But, it only searches for first filter which is /(?i)${jndi/ . It does not search for 2nd filter. Can someone help me to find out how can I search for multiple strings using one query?

I could not find any example in aws documents and over internet

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

@Zabih Khaliqi your code snipped will only find results, if message is exactly one of the values in the list.

If @Sushil is searching "is string in message" I would suggest something like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter strcontains(@message, "jndi") or strcontains(@message, "lower\:j")
| sort @timestamp desc
```

So using the OR operator of and string operators
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-operations-functions

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` operator, like following:
[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20keyword,message%0A%7C%20filter%20logGroup%20in%20%5B%22example_group%22%5D)

```js
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter @message in ["MyFirstSearchString", "MySecondSearchString", "MyThirdSearchString"]
| sort @timestamp desc
```

Comment: This does not work in the way the OP was asking for. Looking for a string within the message, not the message to literally be equal to it.

Comment: it's a helpful answer though because I was looking for this answer when I did the Google

Answer (score 0):

This woked for me :

fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like /(?i)(${jndi|${${lower:j|${${upper:j|${${::-j)|${/
| sort @timestamp desc